# How to Index Websocket Data Stream

Tags: python, numpy, websocket

I've successfully connected to the Bitstamp websocket and I am now attempting to index the data stream that I receive. Specifically, I want to save bids[0][0] into a best_price variable:

```
{'data': {'timestamp': '1615553987', 'microtimestamp': '1615553987492634', 'bids': [['56355.57', '0.09439734'], ['56347.20', '0.03743896'], ['56346.03', '0.47172493']....etc
```

The problem is that I get a "subscription succeeded" message when I first connect:

```
{'event': 'bts:subscription_succeeded', 'channel': 'order_book_btcusd', 'data': {}}
```

This means I get the following error, because I cannot index the None returned from the empty data steam:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

Here is my code

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import numpy as np

def error_handler(err):
    pass

def handler(msg):
    pass

async def bitstamp_connect(callback):
    uri = "wss://ws.bitstamp.net/"
    subscription =       {
          "event": "bts:subscribe",
          "data": {
            "channel": "order_book_btcusd"
          }
        }

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(subscription))

        while True:
            msg = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
            bids = np.array(msg['data'].get('bids'))
            #print(bids)
            print(bids[0][0])

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(bitstamp_connect(handler))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be easily solved by simply adding an if statement checking if the message received was a 'subscription successful' message or a 'data' message. Change your while loop to the following:

```
while True:
    msg = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
    # Check what type of message we received
    if msg['event'] == 'data':
        bids = np.array(msg['data'].get('bids'))
        print(bids[0][0])
    elif msg['event'] == 'bts:subscription_succeeded':
        # You can put code here if you want to do something when first subscribing
        pass
```